# Is there any way to lock the internal keyboard and trackpad without logging out on mac?

Tags: macbook

Was wondering if there is any quick way of locking the internal keyboard / trackpad on macbook without logging out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, OSX lets you turn off the trackpad in "Universal Access" settings
(but only if you have a mouse attached to the macbook, either with a virtual adapter or physical)

No such possibility is known to me for the keyboard :/